# What is the best way to share the SSH authentication socket with another user?

Tags: ssh, permissions, socket, ssh-agent, ansible

I'm using [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) for setting up a remote server and I'm using SSH agent forwarding to `git clone` a repository from [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org) to use my local SSH key, because I'm using `sudo` I'm preserving the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable using a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory which contains:

```
Defaults env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Which indeed is making this environment variable available when using `sudo`, the problem is when I want to clone as another user `web` that doesn't have permission to access the socket file available at `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Currently I'm setting the ownership of the socket directory recursively for this user so I don't give `0777` permissions for the socket file.

```
$ ls -l /tmp
drwx------  2 web web 4096 Aug  7 09:09 ssh-PcIG22W1CM
```

All of this is done using Ansible but I'm not sharing Ansible code as this issue applies to any other situation.

What is the best practice to share this socket file without giving `rwx` permissions for everyone ?

Answer (score 3):

As root, you might bridge the socket with:

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/authsocket.sock,umask=077,user=web,fork "UNIX:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

**On Linux**, this will prevent other user to `connect()` to this socket.

On Linux, you might be tempted to set an ACL on the socket (`setfacl user:$user:w $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`) but this won't work because the OpenSSH client [checks the EUID](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_7_5_P1/ssh-agent.c#L1101) of the socket and only allows the owner and root.